# Need to select repeated records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select only repeated records from my tables. Query executed successfully but there is no data into it.

My code:

```
SELECT PRACOWNK.X_I, Imie,Nazwisko, HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP 
FROM R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.PRACOWNK 
JOIN R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.HISTORIA on PRACOWNK.X_I=HISTORIA.X_IPracownik
WHERE AktZatrudnienie = 1 
GROUP BY PRACOWNK.X_I,Nazwisko,Imie,HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP
HAVING COUNT(PRACOWNK.X_I) > 1;
```

Could you please help?

Comment: What happens if you remove the HAVING clause?

Comment: A good idea would be to remove the `HAVING` and instead adding `COUNT(PRACOWNK.X_I)` to the `SELECT`, in order to observe if there is some value greater than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SQL Server` you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT PRACOWNK.X_I, Imie,Nazwisko, HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PRACOWNK.X_I ORDER BY PRACOWNK.X_I) AS rn 
FROM R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.PRACOWNK 
JOIN R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.HISTORIA on PRACOWNK.X_I=HISTORIA.X_IPracownik
WHERE AktZatrudnienie = 1 ) xxx
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.  I have changed PARTITION BY to OREDR BY. Now it is still displaying all records except first 2 rows.

Comment: @PawełJaniszek, see edit in answer. if it doesn't work then post the result after running inner sub query and mention what result you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get records based on count of PRACOWNK.X_I then remove this column from  select and Group by.

```
SELECT  Imie,Nazwisko, HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP 
FROM R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.PRACOWNK 
JOIN R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.HISTORIA on PRACOWNK.X_I=HISTORIA.X_IPracownik
WHERE AktZatrudnienie = 1 
GROUP BY  Nazwisko,Imie,HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP
HAVING COUNT(PRACOWNK.X_I) > 1;
```

Comment: It works but shows all records, instead of  repeated.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in your question @PawełJaniszek

Answer (score 0):

Take all data and put into a temporary table.

```
SELECT PRACOWNK.X_I, Imie,Nazwisko, HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP
INTO #temp
FROM R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.PRACOWNK 
JOIN R2P_psou_dane_1.dbo.HISTORIA on PRACOWNK.X_I=HISTORIA.X_IPracownik
WHERE AktZatrudnienie = 1
```

Then check the having condition

```
SELECT * FROM #temp
group by  PRACOWNK.X_I, Imie,Nazwisko, HISTORIA.X_I, HISTORIA.NrKartyRCP
HAVING COUNT(PRACOWNK.X_I) > 1;
```